# ember: query using non standard id in router model hook?

Tags: ember.js

Is there a better way of doing this?

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        //there must be a better way to do this!
        return this.store.find('edition',{ 
          server_id: parseInt(params.edition_id) 
        }).then(function(e){
          return e.get('firstObject')
        });
    }
});
```

I want to find the model from the store using a query, and so I end up with an array rather than just a model...

Many thanks.

Comment: can you not make a search by id? if all you need its one model, then why do you need a search query?

Comment: If your rest endpoint is configured to only work that way then there isn't a better way.  You're putting the filtering on the back of the server, which means Ember Data has no idea how many records are returned it could be between 0...N which is best suited with a collection.